# How to Using Yii2 BaseImage class crop image from center

Tags: yii2

Using tutorial: [How to use imagine ( crop, thumb, effects for images ) on Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/757/how-to-use-imagine-crop-thumb-effects-for-images-on-yii2/) I can crop image in backend. By default it's cropping from `X=0`, `Y=0` coordinates. But I need that it will crop from center.

Someone has Idea how to crop from center?

Comment: Can you give an example? The picture will be better,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know sizes, use `getimagesize`. And original sizes divided on `2`. And you code is like that:

```
 $size = getimagesize($originalImg);
    Image::crop(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/img/text-photo.jpg'), $width, $height, [$size['width']/2, $size['height']/2])
    ->save(Yii::getAlias('@runtime/crop-photo.jpg'), ['quality' => 80]);
```

Comment: Vitalik, thanks for your reply, with your advice I learn how to manage with coordinates, so I solve my issue with different way.

Comment: Wouldn't this _start_ it from the center, as in if the image was `180px` in height then the crop would start from `90px` down, whereas you probably want the _middle_ of the crop to be in the center. :)